# Slick silently fails when no MySQL java driver provided

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

If I have this in my build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= List(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % slickV,
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.40"
)
```

Then following code produces an expected result:

```
    try{
      db.run((for(visitor <- visitors) yield visitor).result.headOption).map(println(_))
    }catch{
      case e:Throwable => e.printStackTrace()
    }finally db.close()
```

But when I remove the last `"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.40"` line from the dependencies then nothing ever happens. I don't get the result printed but what is interesting I don't get any error as well.
Is this an expected behavior of Slick? Could you help me to clarify which driver is being used in this case and what happens? Probably the reason is in `slf4j-nop`, can it be that it hides any errors/warnings output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

Change your code into:

```
  db.run((
      for(visitor <- visitors) yield visitor).result.headOption).map(println(_)
  ).recover {
      case e: Throwable => e.printStackTrace()
  }.onComplete {
      case _ => db.close()
  }
```

**Second:**

I don't know where you run your code but if it is some kind of unit test of `main` method then you probably finish execution before above code is being run (remember `db.run` invokes async execution).

I am not going into details of how you should approach actually handling this properly ( **definitely naive wait/sleep is not a way to code - neither in production code nor in unit tests** ). For the sake of solving your above problem however, let's just put after above code this:

```
Thread.sleep(5000)
```

and let's see if it helps. We can potentially follow up from there if there are further questions.

Comment: this is wonderful. Now I can see the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` exception.
Could I ask a favor so you educate me a bit so I draw some lessons from this.
So `db.run()` returns a `Future` instance. This `Future` instance is scheduled for execution to standard execution context I believe, since I have in that ScalaTest suite this line `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`. So do I understand correctly that the "main" thread apparently terminates quicker than my 'catch{}' clause gets its chance to work?

Comment: Also in the Slick docs I can see this `Every Database contains an AsyncExecutor that manages the thread pool for asynchronous execution of Database I/O Actions.` which is also visible in the `Database.forURL` method signature.
So looks like the Future instance is executed by that execution context. So if I don't place my exception handling in the `recover`, as Future's semantics require then my main thread is already dead. So main thread gets terminated even if myh

Comment: I don't completely get the 2nd comment but generally it's true that your main thread dies in the meantime (whether you use `recover` or not)

Comment: It is precisely when I use `recover` then I can see the stack trace printed. I do not use `Thread.sleep(5000)`.
But I feel a bit ashamed because I forgot that i am dealing with `Future` here and `catch{}` clause will not help even if the future fails :)
So thanks a lot for helping me to bring this case clear for myself.

Comment: And one last question: so the `recover` is also executed not by my main thread but by Slick's DB execution context, right? Seems like this completes my understanding. Even when the main thread terminates, the DB execution context is being held working while there are incomplete futures in the queue, right?

Comment: That is correct. Although be careful with that logic. Above might work in your `main` method but if you do the same in unit test it will usually mean that your test will be marked as successful regardless of what actually happens in your `Future`.

Comment: yes, precisely, that was happening as well. ScalaTest has means to assert on Future-s for such cases, so I know how to deal with it.